# The Pocket SDK has a method to perform an API call, how would I go about using it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, api, ios6

I'm new to this and I can't find much documentation on using this method.

The SDK is found here: https://github.com/Pocket/Pocket-ObjC-SDK

I want to use this method in particular: https://github.com/Pocket/Pocket-ObjC-SDK/blob/master/SDK/PocketAPI.h#L88

In order to use this API call: http://getpocket.com/developer/docs/v3/retrieve which will get me the user's articles.

What do I supply in the method? As I said, I'm new to this stuff in general, specifically delegation and the like, so I'm a little confused how I'd go about implementing this method.

Comment: Is your question about working with delegates or the details of the Pocket API?

Comment: A little bit of both; sorry for the ambiguity. I'm curious of how I'd go about implementing the Pocket API, and if it requires the use of delegation, a little explanation would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

This code below is an example of how to call http://getpocket.com/developer/docs/v3/retrieve with all of the default arguments except count, which I set to 2. This assumes that the user has already been logged in, and that this line was added in AppDelegate per the install instructions

```
[[PocketAPI sharedAPI] setConsumerKey:@"Your Consumer Key Here"];
```

.

```
#import "PocketAPI.h"

[[PocketAPI sharedAPI] callAPIMethod:@"get"
                      withHTTPMethod:PocketAPIHTTPMethodPOST
                           arguments:@{ @"count" : @"2" }
                             handler: ^(PocketAPI *api, NSString *apiMethod,
                                        NSDictionary *response, NSError *error){
                                 NSLog(@"%@", response);
                                 NSLog(@"%@", error);
                             }];
```

If you only want to use default arguments. Use this (nil will not work):

```
arguments:@{}
```